# Removing repetition in function that hides/shows different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery("#royal_edit_button").click(function () {        
    jQuery('#royal_edit_title_edit').show();
    jQuery('#royal_edit_price_edit').show();
    jQuery('#royal_edit_desc_edit').show();
    jQuery('#royal_edit_title_view').hide();
    jQuery('#royal_edit_price_view').hide();
    jQuery('#royal_edit_desc_view').hide();
});     

jQuery("#royal_edit_button_back").click(function () {       
    jQuery('#royal_edit_title_edit').hide();
    jQuery('#royal_edit_price_edit').hide();
    jQuery('#royal_edit_desc_edit').hide();
    jQuery('#royal_edit_title_view').show();
    jQuery('#royal_edit_price_view').show();
    jQuery('#royal_edit_desc_view').show();
});
```

When `royal_edit_button` is clicked, it hides `view` section and shows `edit` section, `royal_edit_button_back` does the opposite.

Is there a way to do this concisely? I'd rather not have to repeat the same code for every element.

Comment: You could apply a class to all of the elements that you want to hide. Then use jQuery to hide all elements with that class.

Comment: ^- That, plus make use of the jQuery's `toggle` function

Comment: You can apply `.hide` to multiple elements at once, you just need to _select_ them in one go: `jQuery('#royal_edit_title_edit, #royal_edit_price_edit, …').hide();` But giving those elements a common class probably makes more sense.

Comment: Hide/show section containers, not individual elements. If you don't have two sections, than create them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this would look better:

```
$("#royal_edit_button").click(function () {        
    $('[id ^=royal_edit_][id $=edit]').show();
    $('[id ^=royal_edit_][id $=view]').hide();
}); 

$("#royal_edit_button_back").click(function () {
    $('[id ^=royal_edit_][id $=view]').show();
    $('[id ^=royal_edit_][id $=edit]').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

If you have html which looks something like this:

```
 <div class="royal-edit-section">
    <button id="royal_edit_button" class="active">Edit</button>
    <button id="royal_edit_button_back">View</button>
    <div class="edit-section selected royal-section">
        <label for="royal_edit_title_edit">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" id="royal_edit_title_edit" />
        <br />
        <label for="royal_edit_price_edit">Price:</label>
        <input type="text" id="royal_edit_price_edit" />
        <br />
        <label for="royal_edit_desc_edit">Description:</label>
        <input type="textarea" id="royal_edit_desc_edit" />
    </div>
    <div class="view-section royal-section">
        <p id="royal_edit_title_view" class="royal-view-item">Title: Sample title </p>
        <p id="royal_edit_price_view" class="royal-view-item"> Price: $10.00</p>
        <p id="royal_edit_desc_view" class="royal-view-item">Description: lorem ipsum dolor </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
jQuery("#royal_edit_button").click(function () {
    jQuery('.active').removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');
    jQuery('.edit-section').show();
    jQuery('.view-section').hide();
});     

jQuery("#royal_edit_button_back").click(function () {
    jQuery('.active').removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');
    jQuery('.view-section').show();
    jQuery('.edit-section').hide();
});
```

Js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cr6v6anz/